# rails pass array link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I have a link

```
link_to 'To basket',order_items_path(order_item:{product_id:[31,32,36]})
```

want to send array of params to contoller but have received

Unpermitted parameter

```
   {"order_item"=>{"product_id"=>["31", "32", "36"]}, "controller"=>"order_items", "action"=>"create"}
"------"
  Order Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 10]]
Unpermitted parameter: product_id
```

but i have it

```
def order_item_params
   params.require(:order_item).permit(:quantity, :product_id,:size)
end
```

So my question is how to correctly send array of params?

Answer (score 2):

You have to change strong params filtering like below:

```
def order_item_params
   params.require(:order_item).permit(:quantity,:size, product_id: [])
end
```

Rails guide said that in section [4.5.1 Permitted Scalar Values](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters)

> To declare that the value in params must be an array of permitted scalar values map the key to an **empty array**.